# Setting a cookie on a subdomain for reading on the main domain?

Tags: php, subdomain, setcookie

I'm trying to set a cookie using PHP on a subdomain (api.example.com) and read it on the main domain (example.com)

My *setcookie* looks like this:
`setcookie("user-hash", $userHash, $expiry, "/", $domain, true, true);`

Where `$domain` has been a few different things over the course of the day e.g. "example.com", ".example.com", "" and nothing seems to work.

I'm now wondering if it is something else, or if is even possible? I've seen plenty of people posting examples of how to set/read a cookie on the main domain but not much the other way around.

My cookies worked fine before I moved this script to the subdomain.

Comment: From a subdomain you can set a cookie for a "parent domain", but not the other way around: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57803192/231316

Comment: ```So subdomain.example.com domain-matches example.com, but example.com does NOT domain-match subdomain.example.com```

so does that mean I need to set my domain to `api.example.com`?

Comment: If you want to set a cookie on api.example.com, the code that sets it must originate from api.example.com, or a subdomain of _that_ such as xyz.api.example.com

Comment: I want to set a cookie on example.com from api.example.com

Comment: For a basic sign in

Comment: I see, I was interpreting it as the other way. Using a leading period for the domain is an older spec, and I'm fairly certain isn't used by any modern browsers, so just `example.com` would be correct for that. You say it isn't working, but have you inspected the network traffic? On api.example.com do you see that cookie in your browser tools? Same with example.com. Ignore PHP/HTML, too, just visit a page and check your tools to see what is in there. You are also setting secure and HTTP only, are those correct?

Comment: And, just to make sure, your domain is not on the PSL? https://publicsuffix.org/list/public_suffix_list.dat

Comment: The secure and httponly flags weren't a problem before my changes - if they need to change though, then I'm not too fussed about them. I'll have to inspect the network on api.example.com but nothing visible on example.com - I'll change the domain to example.com and have a look - thanks.